Linq - How to query json inside Linq
I have this code:
    List<int> cats = new List<int>();

    foreach (var cat in ctx.TblCategories)
    {
        int catCount = ctx.TblProducts
            .Where(x => int.Parse( JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SellItem>( x.ItemJson ).category ) == cat.Id )
            .ToList()
            .Count; <-- errors here
        
        cats.Add(catCount);
    }

//

    public class SellItem
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string specification { get; set; }
        public string additional { get; set; }
        public string colour { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }

        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string postage { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public List<string> images { get; set; }
        public List<string> imagenames { get; set; }

    }

But i get an exception:

The LINQ expression DbSet<TblProduct>().Where(t => int.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SellItem>(t.ItemJson).category) == __cat_Id_0) could not be translated.
Additional information: Translation of method Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to AsEnumerable, AsAsyncEnumerable, ToList, or ToListAsync.
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

How do i resolve this?

Your code is terse to the point of being confusing - you can make it much easier to read and follow by introducing intermediate variables instead of packing complex nested call-sites into argument expressions.

...and that complexity is actually the cause of the problem: EF can only translate
a handful of expression-patterns to SQL - but certainly not JSON deserialization of external data like that...

You can't deserialize data like this on the server side.  SQL doesn't support running newtonsoft on the server !

@Neil I mean, technically it could, if it really wanted to (and especially if it wanted to confuse the newbs who might actually think Linq/EF is capable of unholy kinds of program transformations...

List<int> cats = new List<int>(); is where I stopped reading. A list of numbers is not cats. Maybe catIds. If you can't name things correctly, it's likely that you haven't understood them.

@vc74: a cat is the category of an item to sell? Sounds absolutely plausible...

My advice to the OP is to stop, stop stop storing JSON blobs in an RDBMS and properly normalize it first before even attempting to use anything like Entity Framework - the only way to make this work right now is to either use only raw SQL with horrible JSON_QUERY etc functions (so no Linq) - or even worse: loading the entire table of JSON strings into memory so you can then deserialize it all. There's no redemption here: nuke it and start over.

As Neil says you can't deserialize data on the server side. And the solution is in your Additional information. You need to add .AsEnumerable to switch it to client-side evalutation.
You can try this:
List<int> cats = new List<int>();

foreach (var cat in ctx.TblCategories)
{
    int catCount = ctx.TblProducts
        .AsEnumerable() // Switch to client-side evaluation
        .Where(x => int.Parse( JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SellItem>( x.ItemJson ).category ) == cat.Id )
        .Count;            

    cats.Add(catCount);
}

Hope it will help.

This will work, but bear in mind EVERY record in TblProducts will be pulled from the server to the client to do this. If you only have a few records (or this not called very often), it's a reasonable, if inefficient way to do it.
